# ImportRange Script Quietly catch errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I created my own import range script because I had people inputting data in the middle of my import which then broke.  Also I have hidden sheets that users copy that have imports which they would have to hit the "Request Access" button before it would work.  Plus ImportRange is kinda finicky with large calculation spreadsheets.

Here is my code

```
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
//Script Based ImportRange

//Example importRange_('1Eb8a5Imw9FWz-Ifk2gUMNkg1TXDlLPemy1bmNv_AOcY','Sheet1','A:Z','Dest_Sheet','A1','y')
//Explanation importRange_('Importing Spreadsheet Key','Importing Spreadsheet Tab Name','Importing Spreadsheet Tab's Range','Destination Spreadsheet Tab Name','Destination Spreadsheet Tab's placement','Will add note to the first cell of import')

function importRange_(Source_Key,Source_Sheet,Source_Range,Set_Sheet,Set_Pos,Add_Note) 
{
  var Load = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Source_Key).getSheetByName(Source_Sheet).getRange(Source_Range).getValues();
  var Name = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Source_Key).getName();
  var RowVal = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(Set_Pos).getRow();
  var ColVal = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(Set_Pos).getColumn();
  if(Add_Note.toUpperCase() == 'Y')
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(RowVal,ColVal,1,1).setNote("Import Script Updated On: " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a")+"\nSS Name: "+Name+"\nRange: "+Source_Sheet+"!"+Source_Range+"\nSS Key: "+ Source_Key);      
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(RowVal,ColVal,Load.length,Load[0].length).setValues(Load);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('At: '+Set_Sheet+'!'+Set_Pos,'Import Completed:');
}
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
```

So when I try the `try` & `catch(err)` around:

`var Load = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Source_Key)
            .getSheetByName(Source_Sheet)
            .getRange(Source_Range)
            .getValues();`

I still get a hard error displayed to the end user on the spreadsheet side. Is there a way capture the message quietly and send to the Logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had problems with `try` and `catch(err)`. You should try to use `catch(e)` instead.

You can also try to do `e.message`, `e.filename`, or `e.lineNumber` to narrow down where the issue is popping up